# Why is the base clock in task manager lower than the titled clock speed?

Tags: cpu, performance, clockspeed

Task Manager recognizes that my CPU is a 3.1 Ghz model, but also tells me that the base clock is 3.0 Ghz.

[image]

Comment: It indicates your boosted clock speed and not your base clock speed

Comment: Worth pointing out that the [i7-7920HQ](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97462/intel-core-i7-7920hq-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html) is a 3.10 GHz processor with a boost clock of 4.10 GHz.  It appears your device is being massively thermally throttled.

Answer (score 1):

Manufacturers can adjust the processor performance to fit the thermal limits of their cooling system, adjusting the nominal clock speed and limiting higher clock speeds.

The Intel page for the [i7-7920hq](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97462/intel-core-i7-7920hq-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html) shows it is a 45W TDP processor but has a "Configurable TDP-down" of 35W

> Configurable TDP-down is a processor operating mode where the processor behavior and performance is modified by lowering TDP and the processor frequency to fixed points. The use of Configurable TDP-down is typically executed by the system manufacturer to optimize power and performance. Configurable TDP-down is the average power, in watts, that the processor dissipates when operating at the Configurable TDP-down frequency under an Intel-defined, high-complexity workload.

The 3.1GHz is the nominal processor speed as specified by Intel, it appears that thermal limits of your system have resulted in a slightly lower base clock speed.